# Integral question unable to solve by primitive

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

So I have this integral question and it seems like it's primitive it's not so appealing.... so I'm thinking there should be another way to solve it.... but I seem to can't figure out how.

$\int_0^{2\pi}x\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx$

I entered it on wolframalpha and it seemed like it's answer is 0. So I'm thinking this shouldn't be a coincidence and there must be a smart way to solve this.

Comment: yeah I tried but i end up with arctan(sinx) from 0 to 2pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the substitution $u = 2\pi - x$ to see that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}x\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx = \int_0^{2\pi} (2\pi - u) \frac{\cos u}{2-\cos^2u}du = \int_0^{2\pi} (2\pi - x) \frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx.$$
Take the average of both sides to see that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}x\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx = \pi \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx.$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}x\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx &= \pi \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{2-\cos^2x}dx \\
&= \pi \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d(\sin x)}{1+\sin^2x} \\
&= \pi \left[\arctan(\sin x)\right]_0^{2\pi} \\
&= \pi [\arctan(2\pi) - \arctan(0)] \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You already did integration by parts, giving you the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\arctan(\sin x) dx$. By symmetry, this is the same as $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\arctan(\sin x) dx$, and that integrand is an odd function.

Answer (score 0):

Guideline use $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int _a^b f(a+b-x)$ then after applying it once use $1-\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x)$ and then let $\sin(x)=u$